# Can we have a linux terminal chat client for gmail

Tags: client, terminal, gmail, chat

Does a gmail terminal chat client exist or anyway one can write it?

Comment: The question of whether a GMail terminal chat client exists is not programming related and does not belong on this site. Your second question *is* programming related, but I would suggest you find the answer to the first question first. Your second question is also too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://thinkhole.org/wp/2006/09/20/howto-connect-to-google-talk-with-bitlbee/

It is a command line client which you can configure to use gtalk.